# Fortran: read variables that are not present in a file

Tags: file-io, fortran

I need help understanding this 50 line program

```
  implicit none
  integer           maxk, maxb, maxs
  parameter         (maxk=6000, maxb=1000, maxs=5)
  integer           nk, nspin, nband, ik, is, ib
  double precision  e(maxb, maxs, maxk), k(maxk)
  double precision  ef, kmin, kmax, emin, emax
  logical           overflow

  read(5,*) ef
  read(5,*) kmin, kmax
  read(5,*) emin, emax
  read(5,*) nband, nspin, nk

  overflow = (nband.gt.maxb) .or. (nk.gt.maxk) .or. (nspin.gt.maxs)
  if (overflow) stop 'Dimensions in gnubands too small'

  write(6,"(2a)") '# GNUBANDS: Utility for SIESTA to transform ',
 .                'bands output into Gnuplot format'
  write(6,"(a)") '#'
  write(6,"(2a)") '#                                           ',
 .                '       Emilio Artacho, Feb. 1999'
  write(6,"(2a)") '# ------------------------------------------',
 .                '--------------------------------'
  write(6,"(a,f10.4)")  '# E_F               = ', ef
  write(6,"(a,2f10.4)") '# k_min, k_max      = ', kmin, kmax
  write(6,"(a,2f10.4)") '# E_min, E_max      = ', emin, emax
  write(6,"(a,3i6)")    '# Nbands, Nspin, Nk = ', nband, nspin, nk
  write(6,"(a)") '#'
  write(6,"(a)") '#        k            E'
  write(6,"(2a)") '# ------------------------------------------',
 .                '--------------------------------'

  read(5,*) (k(ik),((e(ib,is,ik),ib=1,nband), is=1,nspin), ik=1,nk)

  do is = 1, nspin
    do ib = 1, nband
       write(6,"(2f14.6)") ( k(ik), e(ib,is,ik), ik = 1, nk)
       write(6,"(/)")
    enddo
  enddo
```

This is a free format Fortran file. The name of the program is gnubands and rearranges numbers in an input (which the user specifies). I would like to know how this program operates. Here is what I do not understand. The program takes input from a file, it reads

```
ef, kmin,kmax,emin,emax,nband,nspin,nk
```

However, all of these variables are not found inside the input file. I opened the input file in vi and conducted a search using /. I do not obtain any results. Nevertheless, the program appears to correctly pick all values. What is happening?
Also, I do not understand the read format

```
read(5,*) (k(ik),((e(ib,is,ik),ib=1,nband), is=1,nspin), ik=1,nk)
```

I am not familiar with the syntax and would like to know what it is saying or any references.

Comment: What do you mean by "these variables are not found inside the input file"?  Are you expecting that there are lines like "ef=23.51667" or so on?  What does the input file look like?

Comment: For your final question, see about [implied do loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11760650).

Comment: @francescalus  To your second question, yes. The input file has variable declarations and a bunch of numbers. However, none of them are declare ef, kmin,etc. They are not even mentioned, i.e. opening the input file in vi and searching "ef" yields no results.

Comment: The file is over 3000 lines long, I don't think it would be a good idea to put it here...

Comment: The entire file if that long would indeed be a terribly bad idea.  But the variables `ef`, `kmin`,`kmax`,`emin`,`emax`,`nband`,`nspin`,`nk`are all read from the first four lines of that file, the program code suggests.  I've no recommendation for a question which explains how a `read` statement works, you should see a language reference/tutorial, but note that (except in cases not applicable here) the numbers are important by themselves: no header or metadata required.

Comment: It doesn't.. I tried searching for them using different captalization (since Fortran is case insensitive) e.g. ef,Ef,eF kmin, Kmin,kMin,KMIN. I was able to find ef as Ef, but the other ones I couldn't...

Comment: what are you searching for? The program reads numbers from the first 4 lines of the file. they will not be identified by name in the file.

Comment: Of course you should the file here! Just don't put all lines, clearly only a couple of lines is sufficient. Then it just reads data in a loop.

Comment: The Fortran (and other languages) I/O works in a way that it writes or reads a variable value to or from the current position in the file. There are some nuances what such a current position is (line, column, byte...) but in the most simple case it just reads the numbers in sequence from the file. It does not seek for any description of the data in the file.

Comment: That doesn't look like *free-form source* to me.  Those `.` at the start of the lines following the `write` statements look like characters in column 6 to indicate a continuation line.  Not that this observation has anything to do with the question, just sayin'

Comment: @agentp You are right.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The program is just old (written in 1995).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Some tutorial PDF of SIESTA](http://personales.unican.es/junqueraj/JavierJunquera_files/Metodos/Structuralproperties/Bands-MgO/Exercise-bands-MgO.pdf) shows that the input for gnubands.f is something like this:

[image]

whose header part is to be read by the first four `read` statements of gnubands.f. With this input, the variables are set as

```
ef    = -5.018...
kmin  = 0.000...
kmax  = 3.338...
emin  = -25.187...
emax  = 143.069...
nband = 18
nspin = 1
nk    = 150
```

by giving the input file from the standard input (assumed unit number 5) as

```
gfortran -o gnubands.x gnubands.f
gnubands.x < your_data_file.bands
```

Note that there are (and should be) no keywords like "ef" or "EF" or "Ef" (capitalization does not matter), because the numbers are directly read into the variables in gnubands.f. This is in contrast to other cases like using XML files, where (human-readable) tags or keywords are embedded in the file itself (e.g., pseudopotential files used by Quantum ESPRESSO). I guess your confusion might be coming from the use of `namelist` for obtaining input values, which looks like

```
namelist /your_inp/ a, b, c
read( funit, nml = your_inp )
```

with an input file

```
&your_inp
a = 1.0
b = "method1"
c = 77
/
```

In this case, the variable names (here, a, b, and c) appear literally in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, `5` (in your `read(5,*)`) is `stdin`, so either 
(1)you are supplying the value, when you are running the code, 
or,(2) I guess when you run the SIESTA, (gnuband is a postprocessor of that) it creates a file, possibly named `fort.5`. Check that.